# Fallout Shelter Mr. Handy Gone Forever?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So Mr. Handy died while battling raiders.  It's body is on the floor in a room.

I know I can revive Mr. Handy by clicking on it's body BUT I accidentally removed that room while rearranging rooms.

Is Mr. Handy gone forever or is there a way for me to get him back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out Mr. handy's body is in the vault door room (first room) by default if you happened to have removed the room where Mr. Handy's body was in.